# Did the microwave listening plot ever yield useful intelligence?

Tags: cold-war, espionage

In *[Spycatcher](https://archive.org/stream/peter-wright-spycatcher/PeterWright-Spycatcher_djvu.txt)* Peter Wright mentions that microwaves can be used to detect sound-waves in a suitable tuned object without the need for it to have an active power source, and that such a device had been successfully tested as early as the 1950s.

> It arose out of the work I had been doing for Brundrett’s committee on
> resonance. I had spent a lot of time researching ways in which
> innocuous objects, like ashtrays or ornaments, could be modified to
> respond to sound waves when radiated with microwaves of a certain
> frequency. If a system could be perfected, it promised enormous
> advantages. The object itself would carry no transmitter or receiver,
> so detection would be virtually impossible. By 1956 we had
> successfully developed prototypes, and decided to attempt an operation
> against the Russian Embassy in London.
>
> One of MI5’s agents at that time was the MP Henry Kirby, who had
> frequent dealings with the Russian diplomatic community. The plan was
> simple. MI5 would design an ornament modified to reflect sound, and
> Kirby  would give it as a gift to the Russian Ambassador.

It seems like this *specific* plan petered out (no pun intended), but given that the prototypes were successful in capturing sounds, were they ever deployed against a foreign power?

Comment: lol. Not that kind of microwave; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6oYPXij640

Comment: Are you aware of [laser listening devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_microphone)? Light, not microwaves.

Comment: @o.m. - I'm aware of those, but I've read a range of sources about spycraft in the Cold War (involving spying on embassies) and this passage stood out for me because I can't recall seeing any other sources that have mentioned this particular method.

Comment: Related perhaps: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Signal

Comment: @JonCuster - Now that is interesting, and could easily be the same sort of tech being used.

Comment: And https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(listening_device)

Comment: @JonCuster - Hmm. That was technically a microwave device because the frequency was more than 300mhz but less than 1ghz